# IPC with a Python subprocess

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, ipc

I'm trying to do some simple IPC in Python as follows: One Python process launches another with `subprocess`. The child process sends some data into a pipe and the parent process receives it.

Here's my current implementation:

```
# parent.py
import pickle
import os
import subprocess
import sys
read_fd, write_fd = os.pipe()
if hasattr(os, 'set_inheritable'):
    os.set_inheritable(write_fd, True)
child = subprocess.Popen((sys.executable, 'child.py', str(write_fd)), close_fds=False)
try:
    with os.fdopen(read_fd, 'rb') as reader:
        data = pickle.load(reader)
finally:
    child.wait()
assert data == 'This is the data.'
```

```
# child.py
import pickle
import os
import sys
with os.fdopen(int(sys.argv[1]), 'wb') as writer:
    pickle.dump('This is the data.', writer)
```

On Unix this works as expected, but if I run this code on Windows, I get the following error, after which the program hangs until interrupted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "child.py", line 4, in <module>
    with os.fdopen(int(sys.argv[1]), 'wb') as writer:
  File "C:\Python34\lib\os.py", line 978, in fdopen
    return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I suspect the problem is that the child process isn't inheriting the `write_fd` file descriptor. How can I fix this?

The code needs to be compatible with Python 2.7, 3.2, and all subsequent versions. This means that the solution can't depend on either the presence or the absence of the changes to file descriptor inheritance specified in [PEP 446](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446). As implied above, it also needs to run on both Unix and Windows.

(To answer a couple of obvious questions: The reason I'm not using `multiprocessing` is because, in my real-life non-simplified code, the two Python programs are part of Django projects with different settings modules. This means they can't share any global state. Also, the child process's standard streams are being used for other purposes and are not available for this.)

**UPDATE:** After setting the `close_fds` parameter, the code now works in all versions of Python on Unix. However, it still fails on Windows.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/) does this.

Comment: I'd prefer a solution that doesn't introduce an additional dependency, especially since I have most of one already. But I might go with this if I have no other option.

Comment: Maybe you could dig through their implementation to see how they do it. It works on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 3):

`subprocess.PIPE` is implemented for all platforms. Why don't you just use this?

If you want to manually create and use an `os.pipe()`, you need to take care of the fact that Windows does not support `fork()`. It rather uses `CreateProcess()` which by default not make the child inherit open files. But there is a way: each single file descriptor can be made explicitly inheritable. This requires calling Win API. I have implemented this in gipc, see the `_pre/post_createprocess_windows()` methods [here](https://bitbucket.org/jgehrcke/gipc/src/tip/gipc/gipc.py?at=default).

Answer (score 2):

As [@Jan-Philip Gehrcke suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28532908/4279), you could use `subprocess.PIPE` instead of `os.pipe()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# parent.py
import sys
from subprocess import check_output

data = check_output([sys.executable or 'python', 'child.py'])
assert data.decode().strip() == 'This is the data.'
```

`check_output()` uses `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` internally.

You could use `obj = pickle.loads(data)` if `child.py` uses `data = pickle.dumps(obj)`.

And the child.py could be simplified:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# child.py
print('This is the data.')
```

If the child process is written in Python then for greater flexibility you could import the child script as a module and call its function instead of using subprocess. You could use `multiprocessing`, `concurrent.futures` modules if you need to run some Python code in a different process.

If you can't use standard streams then *your django applications could use sockets to talk to one another*.

> The reason I'm not using multiprocessing is because, in my real-life non-simplified code, the two Python programs are part of Django projects with different settings modules. This means they can't share any global state.

This seems bogus. `multiprocessing` under-the-hood also may use `subprocess` module. If you don't want to share global state -- don't share it -- it is the default for multiple processes. You should probably ask a more specific for your particular case question about how to organize the communication between various parts of your project.

Comment: The global state I'm referring to is in any imported modules that have directly or indirectly imported Django settings. I've tried creating a `multiprocessing` process that changed the value of the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable and then imported Django, but this didn't work because Django had already been imported in the child process before any of my own code had the chance to run.

Comment: @Taymon: comment is probably is not appropriate place to answer it that is why I've suggested to ask a new question. But I see a trivial workaround: do not import prematurely in the main process, do it in children's initializers  instead, set `os.environ` and import whatever is necessary there: the only code that is affected is the code that spawns multiple processes, the rest works the same.