# Python script that is able to receive and send input to another script interactively

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

I am trying to code a Python script that will execute another script and then interact with that script.  By "interact" I mean send and receive input.

Here is how it should flow:

Script1 executes Script2 and waits for input from Script2.

Script1 receives input from Script 2 then sends back output to Script2.

This is repeated 2 or more times.

Lastly, I would like the whole process to be visible in the shell.

Here is the code I am feverishly trying to get to work:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

output1 = '1234'
output2 = '12345'
output3 = '123456'

p = subprocess.Popen(['receiver.py'], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

input1 = p.stdin.read()
print(input1)
p.stdin.write(output1)
p.communicate()[0]

input2 = p.stdin.read()
print(input2)
p.stdin.write(output2)
p.communicate()[0]

input3 = p.stdin.read()
print(input3)
p.stdin.write(output3)
p.communicate()[0]

p.stdin.close()
p.stdout.close()

quit()
```

Comment: Got a summary of what is happening, since you have told us what you expect?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "process to be visible in the shell"? That could be anything from printing to `sys.stdout` to making subprocess calls in shell. On the other had, this sounds like a great application for concurrent programming with `asyncio` or at least a "manager" for both scripts that can handle their interplay.

Comment: @SunnyPatel The current error I am receiving is: ```  File "receiver.py", line 4, in <module>
    input1 = input('First input line to receive.\n')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr```

Comment: @BrianJoseph I will execute the first script in a Terminal, so I would like to see the input and output as printed lines in the terminal.

Comment: @BrianMc did you try searching for that error specifically? Some people are saying you need to flush `p.stdin` and `p.stdout` before closing, some wrap those in try blocks.

Comment: @SunnyPatel Script1 is failing after receiving the first input from Script2, for some reason Script1 cannot detect the EOF.  Will flushing stdin and stdout fix that?

Comment: You'll want to do your reading from `p.stdout`, and writing to `p.stdin`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic communication between main and subprocess in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060274/dynamic-communication-between-main-and-subprocess-in-python)