# Running the next step of a generator in a separate process

Tags: python

How would it be possible to resume a generator in another process.

Assume the following:

1. The processes have access to the same code
2. The scope should propogate between iterations
3. If necessary modify the python interpreter itself

An example of the kind of generator

```
def simple_generator():
    # do some stuff in process one
    yield
    # do some stuff in process two
```

Comment: Have you tried to do something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54060274/dynamic-communication-between-main-and-subprocess-in-python already?

Comment: @mkrieger1 This isn't just communication I want the generator to resume in the other process (scope and all)

Comment: This sounds like an x y problem. Describe the original problem, not your attempted solution.

Comment: Nah not an x y problem I'm legitimately asking how to pause a generator in one process and how to resume it in another

Comment: The simple answer is you can't, and you should instead be describing why you want to be able to do something like that.

Comment: Well you do want to communicate the internal state of the generator (and maybe more) from one process to the other.